# Список из двух и более значений

Tags: c#, массивы, list

Как создать в классе список, который имеет несколько значений?
Грубо говоря, сделать что-то, на подобие:

```
List<int,int,double,int> array = new List<int,int,double,int>();
array.Add(4,5,4.3,5);
Console.WriteLine(array[0][2]);
```

Comment: завернуть нужные данные в структуру? Или использовать кортежи: `Tuple<int,int,double,int>`

Comment: @vp_arth ну это как вариант, я думал, можно сделать намного проще) Про кортежи посмотрю, спасибо

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
List<Tuple<int,int,double,int>> array = new List<Tuple<int,int,double,int>>();
array.Add(Tuple.Create(4,5,4.3,5));
Console.WriteLine(array[0].Item3);
```

---

ValueTuple:

```
List<(int,int,double,int)> array = new List<(int,int,double,int)>();
array.Add((4,5,4.3,5));
Console.WriteLine(array[0].Item3);
```

Comment: Про свежий синтаксис `ValueTuple` добавьте - с ним пользоваться гораздо удобнее

Comment: @Андрей, спасибо, добавил